# Gradle way of publishing into artifactory

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I created a repository with gradle layout in Artifactory. 
With artifact path patterns as

```
[org]/[module]/[baseRev](-[folderItegRev])/[module]-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev])(-[classifier]).[ext]`
```

And Distinctive Descriptor Path Pattern as

```
[org]/[module]/ivy-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev]).xml
```

Question is how to resolve the latest `fileItegRev` belonging to a `baseRev`

For e.g, Let's say I post a jar file in path `org/module/1.0-20170411/module-1.0-20170411.jar`, with `fileItegRev/folderItegRev` being the currentdate / timestamp. Now I would like a path such as `org/module/1.0-latest` to resolve to the latest jar file belonging 1.0 baseRev `1.0`.

Am a newbie, So bear with me if I am loose on terms.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying is Having a base version like say 0.2 and then have multiple builds under it with ability to resolve 0.2.latest to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using dynamic versions support in gradle.